# Why didn't the amomalous voting detection algorithm seem to work for this user?

Tags: discussion

Within the past two hours, this [user](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/4864/ron-maimon?tab=reputation) has been downvoted nine times, twice on the same question. It looks to me that someone has an agenda against this person, so why hasn't this anomalous voting pattern been detected and nulled by the system?

Comment: BTW what is a "voting ring", I have heard about this term here recently. If a voting ring is more than one person attacking the posts of a certain user, could the system find out about and revert this too ?

Comment: @Dilaton The exact definition that the script uses for "voting ring" is super duper tippy top seceret (tm) to prevent people from gaming the definition, but it roughly means some cliche of users that vote for each other at an anomulous rate.

Comment: Hmmm...seven are within six miutes of each other, and not evenly spaced which admits the possibility that they were cast in good faith (i.e. after reading and conssidering each question) as well as a deliberate attack.

Comment: @Dilaton see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137448/term-for-vote-cartels

Answer (score 6):

Because the user in question has had a lot of votes already it will be a while before any new concerted effort will show up in the moderator tools. I'll look into it anyway, but I'm not optimistic.

In the mean time, the script runs at pretty low frequency and we are advised to tell worried uses to wait two days before asking us to escalate.

---

I asked the team to look into it. They report nothing actionable.

If there was an attack involved and the responsible party continues it will eventually show up on some of our tracking tools. I'll keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 5):

The script runs at night (in the UTC timezone), so it hasn't run yet. Wait for tomorrow, then it should have run and likely invalidated the votes, if they are actual serial downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

It is not (yet?) significantly anomalous pattern according to the criteria used by the system.

Answer (score 1):

The engine would definitely detect this serial voting and will also reverse it for sure...
But, it takes up to a maximum of 24 hours.

If you still have a doubt, you could have a look at my [profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOzJn.png). I was a bit confused on that *serial-upvoted* day. The reversing thing made me laugh on the next day :-)